# role of execution engine, jvm and jit?

Tags: jvm, jit

i've read somewhere that 'execution engine' is part of JVM architecture.

q.1) please confirm role of execution engine inside JVM.

q.2) are JVM and JIT two separate component of execution engine?or, JIT is component of JVM only?

q.3) what is the difference between JVM and JIT?

Answer (score 0):

JVM

**A specification** where working of Java Virtual Machine is specified. But implementation provider is independent to choose the algorithm. Its implementation has been provided by Sun and other companies.

**An implementation** Its implementation is known as JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

**Runtime Instance** Whenever you write java command on the command prompt to run the java class, and instance of JVM is created.

The JVM performs following operation:

```
 Loads code

 Verifies code

 Executes code

 Provides runtime environment
```

JVM provides definitions for the:

```
  Memory area

  Class file format

  Register set

  Garbage-collected heap

  Fatal error reporting etc.
```

JLT

In the Java programming language and environment, a just-in-time (JIT) compiler is a program that turns Java **bytecode** into instructions that can be sent directly to the processor.

After you've written a Java program, the source language statements are compiled by the Java compiler into **bytecode** rather than into code that contains instructions that match a particular hardware platform's processor. The **bytecode** is platform-independent code that can be sent to any platform and run on that platform.

Answer (score 0):

### JVM can be divided into three main components

- ClassLoader
- Runtime Data Area
- Execution Engine

---

JIT is in Execution Engine to make the interpretation more efficiently.